# Datatables Server-side C#: warning - parameter 0 for row 0

Tags: c#, datatables

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "../../WebPost/AjaxPinToFolderSearch",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        d.postID = globalPinToFolderSearchID;
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "Folder", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" },
                        { "data": "Pinned", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" },
                        { "data": "StartDate", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" },
                        { "data": "EndDate", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" }
                    ]
                }
            });
```

With example response (taken from developer tools Network Response):

```
{"data":[{"Folder":"Home/Test One/Frogger","Pinned":false,"StartDate":"\/Date(18000000)\/","EndDate":"\/Date(18000000)\/"}]}
```

Datatables appears to be working correctly in that it is requesting and receiving data.  The error pops up, the table displays empty rows (responsive - 1 row of data = 1 row in table).  I realize this is a common question, but I cannot figure out what is wrong.  As a note, backend is C#.

Comment: check whether you have initialized the datatable twice for the same table

Comment: Not initialized twice.  As a note, it would give an error message if initialized twice (something I've experienced recently =) )